# Custom jQuery not triggered/working after gravity form default validation error message gets displayed

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravityforms

I am adding custom jQuery to display certain fields on the basis of conditional logic. For eg: When a "Business Type" field value is selected as Company, "Company Name" and "Company Website" fields are displayed. Otherwise, these fields are hidden.

[image]

Everything works fine until the gravity forms default validation messages are displayed. When the validation error messages are present, `#input_2_8` change event doesn't get fired. Please, can anyone help me with this?

[image]

To display/hide Company fields depending on Business type value

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Hide the fields by default
    $('#input_2_9').css('display','none');
    $('#input_2_10').css('display','none');
    $('#input_2_8').on('change', function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.val() === 'Business') {
        $('#input_2_9').fadeIn();
        $('#input_2_10').fadeIn();
    }else{
        $('#input_2_9').fadeOut();
        $('#input_2_10').fadeOut();
        }
   });

});
```

If anyone wants to have a look at the form then here is the url: https://gems-precious.com/form/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's very simple himani

Comment: Just put the same code for submit button action, I mean button on click event

Comment: You mean on change code inside submit button click event? Change event isn't fired at all

Answer (score 1):

After the Gravity validates the fields, the Gravity form will re-render all the fields, so the script code you write will not be bind to the new element. So you need to bind it again (after validation) or use this hook `gform_post_render`.

As follows:

```
jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(){
    console.log('gform rendered');
    //Your custom scripts code
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. This is exactly what helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Hide the fields by default
    jQuery('#input_2_9').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#input_2_10').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#gform_submit_button_2').on('click', function(e){
    var self = jQuery('#input_2_8 :selected').text();
    if(self == 'Business') {
        jQuery('#input_2_9').fadeIn();
        jQuery('#input_2_10').fadeIn();
    }else{
        jQuery('#input_2_9').fadeOut();
        jQuery('#input_2_10').fadeOut();
        }
   });

});
```

Comment: If you still problem?T hen tell me

Comment: Himani it's time to leave office so please be here so we quickly get the solution

Comment: I will try to, as I have to get off from my screen soon. Otherwise will let you know by tomorrow if it works or not

Comment: I will be able to try your solution tomorrow morning. Thanks for the help, will let you know ASAP tomorrow

Comment: No problem, just an update! The solution you provided didn't work :(